# Xubuntu and gtk apps problem

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, gtk, xubuntu

After upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.10 I got disappointed with "Unity". I wanted my old-style Gnome 2 back. That's why i purged "Unity" and installed Xfce4. But, now i have a problem: All my Gtk+ apps i have used to (like Totem) have "Windows 95" kind of interface...they look very bad. Is there any "libgtk" I should install to fix that? Currently, i have "libgtk-3.0" installed but i'm kind of new to Linux so i don't even know if instaling some old "libgtk" would solve my problem.
Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the theme of GTK applications by editing (resp. creating) `~/.gtkrc-2.0` to use installed themes, for example (adjustment needed!)

```
include "/usr/local/share/themes/ThinIce/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
```

What you need to install is some `gtk2-engines-*` package.

According to [this](http://xubuntublog.wordpress.com/tag/gtk-themes/), you can also use some GUI tool to choose a theme, Applications->Settings->User Interface Settings.

By the way,

> I wanted my old-style Gnome 2 back
>   [so I] installed Xfce4.

kind of confuses me.

Comment: First method won't work (i have created ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file) tried with gtk2 themes in "/usr/share/themes/" and with gtk2 themes in "~/.themes" with no luck. Installed gnome-tweak-tool, when i change my theme there there's no result at all. And yes, I HATE that new "revolutionary" Unity and Gnome3 "Tablet look" but (as it seems) i can't downgrade back to gtk2 so i started using XFCE.

Comment: Hmm strange (the important bit is not where the theme is installed but that the `include` refers to the right file). Also this is a bit more thorough: [XFCE wiki on GTK themes](http://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes)

Comment: When i install clean Xubuntu (virtual machine) and then Totem, Totem has nice gtk theme by default... :\ It seems it's time to reinstall whole system again... I generally don't like Ubuntu because after few years of those "every six months major upgrade" system my computer starts acting...unusual :\ When I setup my system once, i want it to work nice for at least 3-4 years :))) Maybe i should start using Debian :)

Comment: have you tried to install gtk-themes via software center? try a search for "shiki-colors" and install "shiki-colors" and "shiki-colors-xfwm-theme" for example